# Trying to find XML for XSLT in commerce server 2009

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to get XPath from XML so that i can use XSLT to retrieve the data from XML.My problem is i cannot see the XML and i need it to give a XPath in XSLT. How can i know that which XSLT is using which XML. I am working on Search Web Part of Commerce Server 2009.

Comment: You have to show your XML, XSLT and XPath work. So that others can help you. Without showing your work nobody can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tsheten,

I feel your pain. First off, let me help you better understand the architecture of the SharePoint Extensibility Kit you are working with. In the extensibility kit, as you have probably seen, there are 2 main projects that control the execution of search and the transformation and presentation of the results.

### CONTROLLER LAYER

If you open up the Microsoft.Commerce.sln solution, navigate to the Portal > Common > Controllers folder. Here you will see all of the controllers that contain code for creating and executing CRUD operations (CommerceQuery, CommerceUpdate, CommerceDelete and CommerceCreate) against the Commerce Server Foundation.

Inside the SearchController.cs you will see there is a method named DoProductQuerySearch. This method is responsible for executing a product query via the Commerce Foundation. See the snippet of code below for an example of what I'm talking about:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a product query search.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="catalogName">The catalogName</param>
    /// <param name="categoryName">The categoryName</param>
    /// <param name="requiredProperties">The required product properties</param>
    /// <param name="searchPhrase">The search phrase</param>
    /// <param name="whereClause">The where clause</param>
    /// <param name="orderKey">The property by which the search results should be sorted.</param>
    /// <param name="sortOrder">The direction by which the search results should be sorted.</param>
    /// <param name="recordIndex">The index of the first result to return</param>
    /// <param name="recordsPerPage">The number of records to return.</param>
    /// <param name="totalResultCount">An out parameter for the totalResultCount.  That is, the total number of hits for the search.</param>
    /// <returns>A list of Products.</returns>
    public static List<Product> DoProductQuerySearch(string catalogName, string categoryName, List<string> requiredProperties, string searchPhrase, string whereClause, string orderKey, Microsoft.Commerce.Contracts.Messages.SortDirection sortOrder, int recordIndex, int recordsPerPage, out int totalResultCount)
    {
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

        var query = new CommerceQuery<CatalogEntity, CommerceCatalogFullTextSearchBuilder>();
        query.SearchCriteria.Catalogs.Add(catalogName);
        query.SearchCriteria.FirstItemIndex = recordIndex;
        query.SearchCriteria.FullTextSearchType = CommerceFullTextSearchType.FreeText;
        query.SearchCriteria.NumberOfItemsToReturn = recordsPerPage;
        query.SearchCriteria.ReturnTotalItemCount = true;
```

### PRESENTER LAYER

The SearchController.DoProductQuerySearch is called by the Search Results Presenter class. To find this class, navigate to the Portal > UI > Search folder and open the SearchResultsPresenter class. In the SearchResultsPresenter.cs class there is a GetProductQuerySearchResults method that makes a call to return a list of Commerce Entities. In this method you will see something close to the code below:

```
       Collection<Product> products = new Collection<Product>(productResults);

            // Set the products in the View
            this.View.Products = products;

            **ProductXml productXml = new ProductXml(this.GetPropertyCollection(this.View.SearchRequiredProperties), products);**

            XsltArgumentList xsltArgList = new XsltArgumentList();
            xsltArgList.AddParam("DefaultImagesRepository", string.Empty, SiteContext.Current.DefaultImagesRepository);
            xsltArgList.AddParam("_catalog", string.Empty, SiteContext.Current.DefaultCatalogName);
            xsltArgList.AddParam("secondSearch", string.Empty, secondSearch);
            xsltArgList.AddParam("_currentDate", string.Empty, DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
            xsltArgList.AddParam("_OnlineSearch", string.Empty, this.onlineSearch);

            this.RenderResults(xsltArgList, productXml.ToString());
```

The ProductXml class contains what you are looking for. Navigate to Portal > UI > Catalog >Business folder and double click on ProductXml.cs. Here you will see that this class is the XML representation of a product object. It contains a bunch of helper methods that render various parts of the XML. It uses StringBuilder.Append to manually build an XML document and return it to the SearchResultsPresenter for display. Here in the example below you can see that for each product in the search results, the OutputProducts helper method calls another helper method to manually build the XML elements that make up the XML document.

```
   private string OutputProducts()
    {
        StringBuilder xmlSb = new StringBuilder(this._products.Count * 512);

        xmlSb.Append(XmlElementStartOpen); // <
        xmlSb.Append(XmlRootNodeName);
        xmlSb.Append(XmlElementStartClose); // >

        foreach (Product item in this._products)
        {
            this.OutputCatalogItem(xmlSb, item);
        }

        xmlSb.Append(XmlElementEndOpen); // </
        xmlSb.Append(XmlRootNodeName);
        xmlSb.Append(XmlElementEndClose); // >

        return xmlSb.ToString();
    } 
 private void OutputCatalogItem(StringBuilder xmlSb, ICommerceEntity catalogItem, string xmlNodeName)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(xmlSb != null, "The value of xmlSb should never be null.");

        xmlSb.Append(XmlElementStartOpen); // <
        xmlSb.Append(xmlNodeName);
        xmlSb.Append(" ");
        xmlSb.Append(Product.PropertyName.Id);
        xmlSb.Append(XmlAttributeEqualAndQuote); // ='
        xmlSb.Append(catalogItem.Properties[Product.PropertyName.Id]);
        xmlSb.Append(XmlAttributeQuote); // '
        xmlSb.Append(XmlElementEndClose); // >

        this.OutputProperties(xmlSb, catalogItem, this._productProperties);

        this.OutputRelatedCatalogItems(xmlSb, catalogItem, HierarchicalCatalogEntity.RelationshipName.CrossSells, XmlCrossSellsNodeName);
        this.OutputRelatedCatalogItems(xmlSb, catalogItem, HierarchicalCatalogEntity.RelationshipName.UpSells, XmlUpSellsNodeName);
        this.OutputRelatedCatalogItems(xmlSb, catalogItem, HierarchicalCatalogEntity.RelationshipName.KitContents, XmlKitContentsNodeName);

        this.OutputCategoryProducts(xmlSb, XmlCategoryProductsNodeName);
        this.OutputRelatedCatalogItems(xmlSb, catalogItem, Product.RelationshipName.Variants, XmlVariantsNodeName);
        this.OutputPersonalNotes(xmlSb);

        xmlSb.Append(XmlElementEndOpen); // </
        xmlSb.Append(xmlNodeName);
        xmlSb.Append(XmlElementEndClose); // >

        xmlSb.ToString();
    }
```

So, as you can see, there is not a simple schema out there that exists to help you write your xpath queries because the XML is manually built by the ProductXml class. You have two options to make your life easier writing your xpath in your webpart's associated XSLT template.

### OPTION 1: (Bad option) Manually parse through the ProductXML file

This option requires you to read through the entire ProductXML file to gain an understanding of the Element and Attribute structure that it emits for a given set of search results.

### OPTION 2: (Better option) Use Visual Studio debugger to make a sample XML file

If you want to create a sample file of XML to help you write your XPATH, you need to put a breakpoint on the following line in the SearchResultsPresenter.GetProductQuerySearchResults method on the following piece of code:

```
    **this.RenderResults(xsltArgList, productXml.ToString());**
```

Debug the w3wp.exe worker process and when you hit this breakpoint, add the productXml.ToString() to the watch window and change the viewer in Visual Studio to allow you to view the output in the watch window as XML. Then copy the xml to notepad. This will allow you work from a sample XML output when programming your changes in your XSLT template so that your XPath is properly traversing the DOM.

### UPDATED RESPONSE TO "CANBEDOWNLOADED PROPERTY IS NOT RETURNING"

The search properties retrieved by the Search Web part are controlled by the Product Property Picker found by navigating to the Private Site Intranet version of your SharePoint site, and selecting "Modify Shared Web Part" from the web part properties menu. In there you will find an areas to specify which properties should be returned in the product query.
Changing the active properties to return effectively changes what properties are requested for the Product Commece Entity from the Commerce Foundation when the DoProductQuerySearch is executed by the SearchController. It is likely that your XSLT is failing because the properties to return collection does not contain the CanBeDowloaded property because the web part is not passing it back to the controller. I would put a breakpoint inside of SearchController.DoProductQuerySearch and take a look at the properties being passed in. Put a breakpoint on the line immediately following the one below:

```
 var query = new CommerceQuery<CatalogEntity, CommerceCatalogFullTextSearchBuilder>();
```

Then, add query.Model.Properties to the watch window in the debugger and see if that property you are looking for in your XPATH statement is actually being set to return. If you are getting that property to come back in another webpart, then it means that your configuration of that property in your MetaDataDefinitions.xml file is correct, so that's not the culprit. It's likely a simple matter of your webpart not being properly configured to request the CanBeDownloaded property in your product query.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am working on it. When i use PartSearchWebPart then i am using Xpath                                          <xsl:if test="properties/property[@name='CanBeDownloaded'] = 'true'"> and i want to use the same Xpath on SearchWebPart too but it is not working. I thought may be i was using wrong Xpath so i wanted to see the XML. My approach may be wrong, if you have any idea please let me know. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: <xsl:if test="properties/property[@name='CanBeDownloaded'] = 'true'">
                              <a target="_blank" class="free-download">
                                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                  <xsl:value-of select="properties/property[@name='Link']"/>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:text>Free Download</xsl:text>
                              </a>
                            </xsl:if>

Comment: Awesome!!Thanks a lot!! How can i add the CanBeDownloaded property in web-part? I am new to this technology so forgive me for asking silly questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in the web part properties. The post above has it. If you are using the default extensibility kit, you should be able to simply add it using the product picker.